# Иконка для базы данных в шрифте font awesome

Tags: шрифты

Имеется ли подобная иконка в font awesome и если да, то как она называется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этой иконки нету, возможно вы показываете картинку.

попробуйте эту

[fa-database](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/database/)